# Libfreenect macOS Big Sur Python 3.9.7 - Failing to build wrappers

Tags: python-3.x, macos

I tried to use python3 setup.py install but this happens on ubuntu it worked fine...

```
freenect.c:8444:134: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
...__pyx_t_2); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_3); __pyx_t_2++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[1]; __pyx_lineno = 794; __pyx...
^~~~~~~
freenect.c:10210:31: error: no member named 'tp_print' in 'struct _typeobject'
__pyx_type_8freenect_CtxPtr.tp_print = 0;
freenect.c:11450:22: warning: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                  (PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(**name) != PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(key)) ? 1 :
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

This is hinted at elsewhere a few places, but in case anyone comes across this downgrading Python to 3.8 solved the issue for me.

This appears to by a Cython compatibility issue. Perhaps this won't be an issue for Cython 3.0+, but for now this works on my Intel OS X Monterey install.